# user management cookbook error

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am using the following cookbook from the github https://github.com/FFIN/user_management

Unfortunately i keep getting this error when i run the recipe

`ERROR: undefined method each for nil:NilClass`

The error seems to be originating from the second line from this block of code. Seems it's not recognizing .each as a method. Any ideas why? My data bag is the same as the author so i doubt that is the problem.

`sudoer_users = Array.new()
    node['user_management']['users'].each do |user|
        user_management user['username'] do
            comment user['comment'] unless user['comment'].nil?
            create_home user['create_home']
            shell user['shell'] unless user['shell'].nil?
            password user['password'] unless user['password'].nil?
            uid user['uid'] unless user['uid'].nil?
            gid user['gid'] unless user['gid'].nil?
            ssh_keys user['ssh_keys'] unless user['ssh_keys'].nil?
            delete_home_when_remove user['delete_home_when_remove'] unless user['delete_home_when_remove'].nil?
            if user['action'] == 'remove' then
                action :remove
            else
                action :create
            end
        end`

**EDIT**

I went ahead and defined `['node']['user_management']['users']` in my attributes to point my data bag `default['user_management']['users'] = chefusers`.

I also changed

`node['user_management']['users'].each do |user|` to

`node['user_management']['users'].each_line do |user|`

but now i am getting a

`You must supply a name when declaring a user_management resource` error.

The error seems to be happening at the third line of the code block.

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue is that `node['user_management']['users']` is not being set. Double check that your role or whatever else you think is setting that attribute is actually doing something.

Comment: Thanks coderanger. I have edited the question to account for your suggestion.